# Convert Array of list [(value)] or list of list ((value)) to list or array Flutter

Tags: flutter, type-conversion

I am asking for help because I don't know how to solve this issue.
I am currently mapping on an Array of object with this code to output an array of string :

```
                contexts = snapshot.data!.myContexts
                        .where(
                            (e) => e.organisation.name == organizationValue)
                        .map((e) => e.projects.map((e) => e.name)).toList();
```

The last .toList make the difference in the output value from getting an array of list [()] and a list of list (()).

I wanted to know How I could get only a list of string or an array of string.
Thank you in advance, Weac

Comment: as @esentis pointed out .where returns iterable thus you have list inside list. You can use .firstWhere or first get list with .where and iterate over it and add mapped objects to string to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try creating the list this way ?

```dart
final organization = snapshot.data!.myContexts
                        .firstWhere(
                            (e) => e.organisation.name == organizationValue);

contexts = List<String>.generate(organization.projects.length,(index)=>organization.projects[index].name);
```

Assuming the organization is always unique and you can't have two organization with the same name.